# How a ResultSet work with SQL data type

Tags: java

How a `ResultSet` keep the result of a query ?

**EnrollFingerPrint Table**

```
id              int
template        varbinary
Client_Id       int
```

**JAVA**

```
// Query that recover data from mu EnrollFingerPrint table
ResultSet rs = identifyStmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    byte[] templateBuffer = rs.getBytes("template");
}
```

How a `ResultSet` works to keep these query result ?
The `varbinary` column, will be kept on my `ResultSet` like what data type ?

If I keep the template column on a `String` instead, and after that, do a `getBytes` in this `String` it get the same result of the code above ?

Comment: Varbinary would be a byte[] in ResultSet

Comment: If I kept the template in a String  and `getBytes` of this String, will work in the same way ?

Comment: This is the information hiding and abstraction principle in action. You do not need to know how it is done internally, and if it happens that you know, you should not make use of that knowledge. A `varbinary` will most likely be stored in a byte[]. Calling getBytes() on a String will most likely give different results especially with non ASCII characters. Use the appropriate data type for the case at hand. If `template` is text data, then `varchar` is a better choice.

Comment: ResultSet API has specific methods for corresponding datatypes? Why don't you just use that?